# SQLite: complex update statment with inner join

Tags: sqlite, join, sql-update

Ok, I tried almost every solution on this forum and cannot make it work. I always get syntax error. Instead of loading the data and doing the dirty work manually, I am trying to see if I can do it by running only an SQL update query.

I have 2 tables, one contains characters and another contains active effects. I will only display the fields that are important.

**character**

```
pk  name        hp  location
1   duvack      16  2
2   arielle     51  2
3   Larienna    47  2
```

**effect**

```
pk  name       HP   target_id   target_type
4   Paralyze        1           1
5   Seal            1           1
8   Blind           1           1
12  Insanity        1           1
14  Poison    -1    1           1
```

Target_id is a "foreign key" to the character's pk. What I am trying to do is query characters and effects and apply the HP modifier of effects to the characters. So I am basically updating character hp by joining with all effects bound to that character and modifier the character hp with the effect HP.

So for example, with the data above, "Duvack" should lose 1 hp because he is poisoned.

So it should give a query like this:

```
UPDATE character 
INNER JOIN effect ON character.pk=effect.target_id  
SET character.hp = character.hp + effect.HP 
WHERE effect.target_type=1 AND character.location = 2
```

Now I get errors on "INNER" and "JOIN". I get errors on "." for tablename.fieldname . I tried placing SET before the JOIN and it does not work. I think it could be a limitation of SQLite that it cannot support join in update query.

Any other suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

SQLite does not support `JOIN` in `UPDATE` statements.

Instead, replace the `JOIN` with a correlated `SELECT` statement:

```
UPDATE character 
   SET hp = 
     (hp + (SELECT HP FROM effect WHERE effect.target_id = character.pk AND effect.target_type = 1))
   WHERE character.location = 2
```

Comment: In that case, if there are multiple effect that fulfill the WHERE condition, will it update the same character multiple times?

Comment: No, it will fail with a message stating that a scalar value was required but multiple values were returned (or something to that effect).  You must ensure that the inner `SELECT` statement returns only a single row, either by selecting against a UNIQUE index or PRIMARY KEY, or by aggregating the results (eg `MAX(HP)`) or by limiting the results (eg `LIMIT 1`).